# Deleting items in a list in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Tried deleting items in a list, no success.

```
>>> r = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> for i in r:
    if i<3:
        del i


>>> print r
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I even tried filtering it,

```
>>> def f(i):
    True if i>2 else False


>>> print list(filter(f,r))
[]
```

I do not understand why the first one is not working. And I dont understand the result at all, when I use `filter(function,iterable)`.

**EDIT:**

Seeing Paulo's comment below, now I do not understand why this works.

```
>>> for i in r:
    if i<3:
        r.remove(i)


>>> print r
[3, 4, 5]
```

Shouldn't the iterator problem be still there, and shouldn't the code end up removing only the first element (`r[0]`)

Comment: use `some_list.remove(item)` instead of `del(item)`.

Comment: As a side note, `i>2` is already true or false, so you don't need `True if i>2 else False`, just `i>2` does the same thing. But you _do_ need to `return` that result.

Comment: @PauloScardine: That's almost always a bad idea. Besides the fact that it leads to the same problems mutating a list as you iterate over it, it also means you end up repeatedly searching the list for values that you already know how to find, and it generally doesn't do what you want when the list has multiple copies of the same item, and so on.

Comment: _it also means you end up repeatedly searching the list for values that you already know how to find, and it generally doesn't do what you want when the list has multiple copies of the same item, and so on._
What do you mean by that? And why does it work this particular time ?

Comment: @abarnert: it safe to use `list.remove` in python if you loop backwards?

Comment: @PauloScardine: If you don't have any duplicates in the list, it's safe (in practice; I'm still not sure it's actually legal), just as using `del some_list[index]` while iterating in reverse order. But still not a good idea. If you're iterating a list, you have no reason to call `remove`.

Comment: @IMJ: `remove` searches the list to find the value. You're going through the list step by step… and then each time you call `remove`, it starts at the beginning and goes step by step to find the value you gave it. That means it's (a) much slower, and (b) susceptible to finding the wrong one (e.g., when there are duplicate values). If you already know the index (which you can, by using `enumerate` as in Martijn Pieters' answer), just `del r[index]` instead of making `remove` find it again.

Comment: Also, your example at the end does _not_ work. If you run it right after setting `r=[1,2,3,4,5]`, you will end up with `[2,3,4,5]`. My guess is that you ran two incorrect versions in a row—one of them left you with `[2,3,4,5]`, then the next converted that to `[3,4,5]`, so it looked like it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do not understand why the first one is not working.

It is not working because the statement `del i` undefines the variable `i` - that is, it deletes it from the scope (global or local) which contains it.

> And I dont understand the result at all, when I use filter(function,iterable)

Your function, `f` does not contain a return statement. Accordingly, it always returns `None`, which has the boolean equivalent value of `False`. Thus, `filter` excludes all values.

---

What you should probably be doing is filtering using a comprehension, and replacing the list, like so:

```
r = [i for i in r if i >= 3]
```

Or, if you really do want to delete part of the original list and modify it, use `del` on a slice of the list:

```
del r[:3]
```

---

> Seeing Paulo's comment below, now I do not understand why [using `remove`] works.

Because `remove(r)` searches for the value `r` in the list, and deletes the first instance of it. Accordingly, repeated modification of the list does not affect the iteration that happens inside `remove`. However, note that it is still susceptible to the same error, if removal of an item leads to an item being skipped in iteration of the list.

Comment: aah! great explanation of `remove()`

Comment: `remove` will not always work.  Consider `l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, then `for i in l: l.remove(i) if i > 2 else None`.  Result is  `[1, 2, 4]`. (Used conditional operator because comments don't allow multiline code.)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Fair comment.

Comment: The explanation about `remove` here is misleading. It didn't work because `remove` does anything different than the `del` in Martijn Pieters' answer; it worked because he gave it the wrong input. Try the code the OP actually described, and you will get `[2, 3, 4, 5]`, not `[3, 4, 5]`. Unless you accidentally run it twice in a row, which I suspect is what he did.

Answer (score 10):

Use a list comprehension instead:

```
[i for i in r if i >= 3]
```

and retain instead of delete.

Your filter never *returned* the test; so you always return `None` instead and that's false in a boolean context. The following works just fine:

```
def f(i):
    return i > 2
```

Your initial attempt failed because `del i` unbinds `i`, but the list remains unaffected. Only the local name `i` is cleared.

If you want to delete an item from a list, you need to delete the index:

```
del r[0]
```

deletes the first element from the list.

Even if you did manage to delete *indices* the loop would have held some suprises:

```
>>> for i, element in enumerate(r):
...     if element < 3:
...         del r[i]
... 
>>> r
[2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This version fails because the list iterator used by the `for` loop doesn't know you deleted elements from the list; deleting the value at index 0 shifts up the rest of the list, but the loop iterator looks at item 1 regardless:

- first iteration,  `r = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, iterator index 0 -> `element = 1`
- second iteration, `r = [2, 3, 4, 5]`,    iterator index 1 -> `element = 3`

Comment: aaah! I see! BTW, In the first one what do you mean by retain instead of delete ?

Comment: @tMJ: Selecting what you want to keep (retain) instead of removing what you don't want to keep (delete).

Comment: @tMJ He means `r = [i for i in r if i >= 3]`.  This way, you make a new list of the elements you want to keep, not delete the ones you don't want.

Comment: The problem you describe in the last paragraph is very real, but it's not what happens in OP's code, because `del i` doesn't do anything to the list. It only removes the local variable `i` (which is then re-created by the next iteration through the loop).

Comment: OK, I did not understand the explanation about the first attempt. If in the first iteration, (i=0), the first element gets deleted, the list should be printed out as [2,3,4,5], shouldn't it ?

Comment: @delnan: yes, I realized I misread the loop there, and updated.